# Tumblr theme displaying panoramas in negative

Tags: html, css

So at page http://www.lifeofmathias.com/tagged/panorama you can see all the panoramas I've posted. Over a certain width once clicked they should open up in a special view where one can scroll from side to side, however for some reason my theme is doing something annoying and displaying them like this...
[image]

The whole theme code can be found here... http://pastebin.com/4ANY0Hds

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: The live site isn't demonstrating the issue above?

Comment: Did you click on a panorama that opened in the scroll across view?

Comment: In future a link directly to the issue will save others time: http://www.lifeofmathias.com/post/142530725688/griffith-observatory-from-downtown-to-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of theme the following is declared, which is causing the invert effect:

```
<style>
  .tmblr-iframe { 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%); 
    -moz-filter: invert(100%); 
    -o-filter: invert(100%); 
    -ms-filter: invert(100%); 
    filter: invert(100%);
  }
</style>
```

To keep theme updates add the following `css` to the Custom CSS options on the theme customizer:

```
<style>
  .tmblr-iframe {  
    -webkit-filter: invert(0%); 
    -moz-filter: invert(0%); 
    -o-filter: invert(0%); 
    -ms-filter: invert(0%); 
    filter: invert(0%); 
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!